# session not working in webView in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I'm new to android developing. I just create an android app for my website using android webview. when i open my website from mobile browser first time it ask login details and once i logged in and close the browser without deleting cookies , then i open the browser again and visit my website it doe

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    mywebview.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com/");


          }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what is your problem when opening web site on your app?

Comment: You can use this library https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView
It has a method named webView.setCookiesEnabled(true)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView) library. It has a method named `webView.setCookiesEnabled(true)`

I have used this library in one of my projects where I had to keep the user logged in. This library uses advanced/customized webview and has many other useful features that default android webview lacks.

But if you do not want to use this library , and want to proceed with default WebView, then you can use `CookieSyncManager` that is provided by Android itself.
You can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager)

Comment: Yeah woking fine for api level>21 no need to use CookiesManager......    And I got one point If the website link that you provided uses the session and if that works fine in browser then it will work fine. Otherwise it will not work.   Thank you for your response.

Comment: Kindly upvote the answer if you find it helpful for reaching to your solution or mark correct if your problem was solved. It will help other users.